# Use mongodb data/db data files for restore

Tags: mongodb

Our server is down and have no backups on our dbs. But we were able to get data/db using WinSCP. It would be fortunate if we could use these data files to restore our dbs. I have tried setup mongodb in other server and copied data/db from failed server. As I started mongod instance in the new server it says a compatibility issue with authentication schema that data files from data/db was. So we cannot start mongod. I wonder if there's a work around so we can start a mongod with the old data/db from failed server? Or other way to restore dbs? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same versions of mongodb on both systems? Mongodb v3.0 did bring some compatibility changes.

Comment: Yes, thats what I think because the failed server has 2.4 version and the new one is 3. Is there any other way of solving this other than reinstalling 2.4?

Comment: I would first try to get the data back in the same version, then you could try migrating to a higher version. Be sure to check the docs for any issues you may run against https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/

Comment: Thanks, will try that.

Comment: It was solved by installing same version as what the data files was.